# Ninject Bindings: same interface binded to different types. why works?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

I have three projects

- Application.Infrastructure
- Application.A (has reference from `Application.Infrastructure`)
- Application.B (has reference from `Application.Infrastructure`)
- Application.Web (has reference from all)

In `Application.Infrastructure` i have a generic repository class

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    T FirstOrDefault(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where);
}
```

In `Application.A` i have an implementation of this repository

```
public class ApplicationARepository<T> : IRepository<T>
{
    private readonly IApplicationADBContext _context;
    public ApplicationARepository(IApplicationADBContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    // implementation
}
```

In `Application.B` i have another implementation of the repository interface

```
public class ApplicationBRepository<T> : IRepository<T>
{
    private readonly IApplicationBDBContext _context;
    public ApplicationBRepository(IApplicationBDBContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    // implementation
}
```

In Application.Web i bind the interfaces using Ninject

```
// Bind implementations from Application.A
kernel.Bind<IApplicationADBContext>().To<ApplicationADBContext>().InRequestScope();
kernel.Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(ApplicationARepository<>));

// Bind implementations from Application.B
kernel.Bind<IApplicationBDBContext>().To<ApplicationBDBContext>().InRequestScope();

// Here should fail. I already binded typeof(IRepository<>) to typeof(ApplicationARepository<>)
kernel.Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(ApplicationBRepository<>));
```

Even if i bind the same interface to two different types, without specifying any .Where() clause, it is working and i don't get any errors.

Why? How Ninject knows how to differentiate them?

Comment: What line of code do you expect to fail? The second binding or the line where you try to resolve the interface?

Comment: The interfaces are different.. `BDB` and `ADB` ...

Comment: the second binding when i bind the same interface to another type

Comment: You mean the repositories? Take out the contexts from your example.. it's confusing :(

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Yeah I just realised :)

Comment: Sorry for confusing. I added the comment on the last binding (where i think it should fail)

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I keep the Context there because the implementation of IRepository<T> uses context interface. I think that the context parameter helps differentiating the implementations

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22824/discussion-between-raraitul-and-simon-whitehead)

Comment: @RaraituL Try changing the binding to bind a bound generic interface (such as `Repository<Customer>`, instead of an unbound generic (`Repository<>`). This may cause a failure, I'm not sure if the unbound-ness of the interfaces is causing an error to be masked that would appear at runtime.

Comment: Check this article, I think this explains why/how it works https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Multi-injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is absolutely correct to bind multiple implementations to single interface. You can then let Ninject to inject them as an `IEnumerable`. You can even bind one implementation multiple times.

*For example:*

```
// binding
kernel.Bind<IService>().To<BasicService>();
kernel.Bind<IService>().To<BasicService>();

// injection
private IEnumerable<IService> myServices;

public NeedServices(IEnumerable<IService> myServices)
{
     this.myServices = myServices;
}
```

And you will get a collection of two references to `BasicService`.

The case, where you will get an error, would be if you would try to inject a single implementation. The error will raise when Ninject tries to resolve the dependency (and he does not know which implementation to choose).

```
public NeedService(IService myService)
{
     this.myService = myService;
}
```

**So the resolution is that Ninject does not check if dependencies could be resolved at the time of binding, but at the time when injection should occur.**

And it perfectly make sense, because conditions for some kinds of [Contextual-Binding](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding) could change in time (e.g. if your using `.When(x=> ItIsRightTimeToInjectAImplementation())`.